# Is it possible to use the pi as a wireless usb passthrough to my windows computer?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pi-3b+

I have just recently had a raspberry pi 3 model B+ and thought of a cool project. Being a total beginner at this area, i do not know if it is even possible.

My desktop pc is in a very pecular position in the room and i have not easy access to the USB ports. A usb hub would solve the problem but i could not seem to find a hub that has long cable in my area. I would like to use the pi as a wireless USB passthrough to my windows pc. That means when my pi is connected to the same network as my pc and i plug a usb on the pi it would show up on my pc like the usb was plugged to my pc directly. I could transfer files to and from it, format it, etc.

possible use cases.

- USB hub
- Maybe upload an arduino code through it
- Plug my printer to it

I wonder if anybody else has done it, searching google resulted me to no avail maybe because i do not have the right search term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a tool named **usbip** that you can find in the default Raspbian repository:

```
rpi ~$ apt show usbip
```

and install it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install usbip
```

It should do what you want. It provides server and client components only for Linux. You don't tell us what operating system do you use on your desktop pc but you will also find drivers for MS Window$ on the web. Here you can look at some more details: [Using a remote host's USB port as local USB (Linux and Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19689740/5014688).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will be using it on windows 10. I will mark your answer as correct since it answered the question. If it works is a different story, I will begin testing right away thank you good sir :)